# How do I combine form class values into new variable string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to combine two classes from a form into one new value. I need this for a merchant process (name on card)

What I've tried so far:

```
var nameFirst = $('.nameFirst').val(), nameLast = $('.nameLast').val();
var nameOnCard = nameFirst + nameLast;
```

**EDIT**: Adding HTML Form Code
(This works - if I only call one var class as the "name on card" it gets inputed correct. It's just when I try combing the two that it breaks)

```
<input name="first" type="text" class="nameFirst input-medium" required="" placeholder="Enter your first name">
<input name="last" type="text" class="nameLast input-medium" required="" placeholder="Enter your last name">
```

Here is what my JS file looks like (I'm processing through stripe)

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: ccNum,
            cvc: cvcNum,
            exp_month: expMonth,
            exp_year: expYear,
            name: nameOnCard,
            address_line1: addressLine,
            address_city: addressCity,
            address_state: addressState,
            address_zip: addressZip,
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
```

I can get everything above to process correctly, just not "name"

I also tried combining the two on a hidden input, but since these values are being called on an external JS I wasn't able to get that to work either.

(ideally I would like to add a space between the two also)

I'm not very skilled in JS so explanation would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please also post the relevant HTML code ?

Comment: You want to combine - aka *cancat* - two *form class*  but you're using a value from two fields instead. The operation you have done seems to be ok, what problem you have anyway?

Comment: I think we'll get the answer as soon as we see the HTML part

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You probably have some more elements with class `nameFirst` and `nameLast` on same page - something like `nameFirst input-large` or `nameFirst input-small` - precedent to the markup you show and possibly hidden. In this case their values are picked up instead of the ones you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me (as it should). Can I ask when do you trigger your Javascript code, exactly ? If it is executed before the user enters anything, that's probably what's wrong.

The following code displays the `nameOnCard` variable after 10 seconds. Past those 10 seconds, the variable is set and will not be updated with the changes you make on those inputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form>
        <input name="first" type="text" class="nameFirst input-medium" required="" placeholder="Enter your first name">
        <input name="last" type="text" class="nameLast input-medium" required="" placeholder="Enter your last name">
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
            var nameFirst = $('.nameFirst').val(), nameLast = $('.nameLast').val();
            var nameOnCard = nameFirst + nameLast;
            console.log(nameOnCard);
        }, 10000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```